# Why www part of my website redirects me to some other site?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, multiple-domains

I have no redirect header defined anywhere in my server. But when accessed from mobile phone my client's [domain](http://jenniferkashyap.com) (without `www.`) renders correctly:

[image: When accessing without www.]

But when it is accessed with [`www` included](http://www.jenniferkashyap.com/), it redirects me to some other site. Which seems like is operator specific site:

[image: accessing the site with www]

What's the cause and how to avoid this redirection?

PS: I'm hosting this site as as add-on domain with my multiple domain hosting plan if it helps.

Comment: If you exclude for sure .htaccess or cpanel problems, try doing this: create a brand new html page and access it using www. Also: are you using a CMS?

Comment: Do also a scanner check with tools like https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

Comment: Maybe my operator can't find anything at www and redirecting to it's own portal? All those dns stuffs?

Comment: If your site is safe, that's the most plausible cause. Create on cpanel a redirection from www. to none.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you don't have a CNAME record for the `www` subdomain - so the DNS does not resolve? As you suggest in comments, in such cases, some mobile operators (or in fact some 3rd party DNS servers) intercept the response and serve their own content. Very annoying as it makes it difficult to test for invalid requests - the real response code is often masked.